# Removing duplicate returns from a sql query with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble tweaking a sql query that is returning duplicates. Its a simple query that returns data from a "wishlist". The structure of the wishlist is simple. 6 tables that feed into it:

Products - list of products, Images - list of images, Users - list of users, link_ProductsImages - links products to images, for one-to-many relationship (potentially), Wishlist - links users to products (and to images by proxy)

Here is some sample pretend data that sets up the following scenario. One user (100) has two products in his wishlist (1,2). ProductID 1 has one image associated with it (10), where ProductID 2 has three (11,12,13)

The goal is to have ONE LINE PER PRODUCT returned in the query. Because of the one-to-many of the products to images, Im getting duplicates returned on ProductID 2. Can someone help? I tried a few things I found on StackOverflow but I just can't seem to get the query ironed out.

Products
ProductID - 1,2

Users
UserID - 100

Images
ImageID - 10, 11, 12, 13

Link_ProductsImages
ProductID, ImageID - 1,10   2,11  2,12  2,13

Wishlist
UserID, ProductID  - 100, 1     100, 2

```
  select w.WishlistID, p.*,
    isnull(i.ImageFile, 'na.jpg') as ImageFile
    from Products p
    inner join Wishlist w on w.UserID = 4 and w.ProductID = p.ProductID
    left outer join Link_ProductImage lpi on lpi.ProductID = p.ProductID
    left outer join Images i on i.ImageID = lpi.ImageID
```

Comment: this is not a problem, is the natural behavior. Wich image of those three you want to show?

Comment: if a product has 3 images, it is going to show 3 times. You may use GroupBy and maybe count of images per product row, or show 1 image per  product row, or not include images at all, but as you described above, the result you are getting is as expected.

Comment: It doesnt matter which one, and yes I know the way its behaving is the way its supposed to. Im trying to force it to one return no matter what.

Comment: in that case `distinct` is a solution too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to priortise your images to just return one per wishlist ID:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  w.WishlistID, p.*,
            ImageFile = ISNULL(i.ImageFile, 'na.jpg'),
            ImageNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY w.WishListID ORDER BY NEWID())
    FROM    Products p
            INNER JOIN Wishlist w 
                ON w.UserID = 4 
                AND w.ProductID = p.ProductID
            LEFT JOIN Link_ProductImage lpi 
                ON lpi.ProductID = p.ProductID
            LEFT JOIN Images i 
                ON i.ImageID = lpi.ImageID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE 
WHERE   ImageNumber = 1;
```

Since you have not given any way of prioritising images I have just used `ORDER BY NEWID()` to select one at random. If you have specific logic for choosing an image you can replace this with your logic.

The ROW_NUMBER function basically assigns each image a rank within each wishlist ID, so if you have three images it will assign then 1, 2 and 3. The way it assigns the row number is based on the order by, so if you had `ORDER BY i.ImageFile` it would assign row numbers in alphabetical order of `ImageFile`. The partition by clause is similar to `GROUP BY` and tells the row number function where to reset to 0 each time, so in this case `PARTITION BY WishlistID` ensures that row numbers are unique for each wishlist ID. Then finally the results are limited to just the first row for each wishlist ID, ensuring only one image is returned. Hopefully this sheds a bit more light on the situation.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm not going to lie and say I understand it, but it definitely fixes my problem.

Comment: I have edited to try and give more of an explanation. Hopefully it helps. The documentation I linked to on the function should also help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.WishlistID, p.*,
isnull(i.ImageFile, 'na.jpg') as ImageFile
from Products p
inner join Wishlist w on w.UserID = 4 and w.ProductID = p.ProductID
left outer join Link_ProductImage lpi on lpi.ProductID = p.ProductID
left outer join Images i on i.ImageID = lpi.ImageID
```